# Table row re-rendering the child component in react when mouse over on row

Tags: reactjs

Table row re-rendering the child component in react when mouse over on row.

We are using material ui table.

Comment: This question lacks clarity. You might want to consider reading the guidelines on asking questions

Answer (score 0):

Use `onMouseOver` event listener on your desired target to change the desired property what will in turn force react to trigger a re-render event.